# get item from kendo child grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Having Hierarchy grid, trying to add custom client template with  and item with it. But, don't know how can i get child item. For ex. on parent grid i'm getting item like:

```
.Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Template(e => { }).ClientTemplate("<strong><a  href='" + Url.Action("Details", "Types") + "#= Id #'> #= Name #  </a></strong>").Title("Type Name").Width("30%");
```

How can I make this the same for child grid?

```
.Name("grid_#=Id#")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(e => e.Name).Title("SubType Name").ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("Details", "Types") + "#= e.data.Id #'>#= e.data.Name #</a>");
```

If I will use like: `#= data.Name #` it will display parent data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the #= YOUR CODE # syntax in the child grid, it's executed at the parent level, that's why you get the parent model properties.
To have your code executed at the child level, you must use this syntax : \\# YOUR CHILD CODE \\#
This allows you to mix the use of properties from either parent or child level

Comment: Not works for me, have tried with `\\# Name \\#` and also with `\\# data.Name \\#`. It doesn't display this column

Comment: If you want to display the properties in the HTML, it's \\# =Name \\#

Answer (score 0):

Also i found,  with the solution and code above,  don't leave any spaces.   For instance here's a code snippet

```
Url.Action("_GetFileByCompanyCodeId", "Request")  + "?id=\\#=Id\\#'
```